# schtasks says "could not start" as status

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I added a simple exe to scheduled tasks through C# site. The site is hosted on IIS7 (the exe just shows a message box). This was the command that I run on the C# code:

```
schtasks /create /tn mylbat /tr "the exe path" /ru myuser /rp mypassw /sc daily /st 16:03
```

I can see the task added too. But it doesn't get executed and running `schtasks /query /tn mylbat` through the command line throws "*Could Not Start*" as status.

I can see the trigger and action set properly in the task scheduler.

I believe adding the task is working fine since it adds the proper attributes.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled a lot about it. The procedures to add a task in the scheduler was perfect but the problem was that that if the service or task that we are trying to schedule needs some interaction, the task wont start. `The task has to be one that has no user interaction`.